# How to get Monthwise KPIs in simpliRP ERP

Tags: erp

I wish to see the  month wise report on sales, purchase, receipts and payments. how to find.

I want to find it  in the report, probably save as pdf and send  to top management

Answer (score 0):

Go to report, There is a monthwise report. In that, you can find various month wise reports like sales, purchase, receipts and payments. You can also you view  monthwise quotation, sales orders, etc., You can also filter it by itemwise reports also